# Remove time from Datetime input

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have this field in User table

```
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

When I am registering new user from UI, I have to input BirthDate too. But I can not remove time from DateTime. 
[image: datetimeproblem]
I am obligated to input specific time next to date. How Can I remove it?

Comment: If you are using Razor you could use `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BirthDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?&view=netcore-3.0) or [DateTime.ParseExtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.0) or [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netcore-3.0).**

Sample:

```
myEntity.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(viewModel.BirthDate);
```

Ideal usage would be to get `string` from your UI first, and then convert it using aforementioned methods. This will allow you to safely catch exceptions and handle it properly, regardless of what UI framework you're using.